# Using Python to copy xlsx files from newest subfold in directory and copy into dynamic folder with matching file name of the xlsx files

Tags: python, shutil, os.walk, pathlib

copyfrom = 'C:\Users\lexluthorella\Documents\Test_dir'

copyto = 'C:\Users\lexluthorella\Documents\Fake_sftp

The subfolders in the copyfrom directory are as follows:

C:\Users\lexluthorella\Documents\Test_dir

-November-2022

-December-2022

-January-2023

The subfolders in the copyto directory are as follows:

-Location A

-Location B

-Location C

Im trying to create a script that can dynamically find the newest subfolder in the copyfrom directory (which I did accomplish) and find the xlsx filenames that "match" with the copyto subfolders and copy the xlsx files into the respective subfolder. Another twist is that the file naming convention for the xlsx documents is more like "Location A...-2023 Monthly file.xlsx". The subfolders in the copyto just have the Location Name.

Below is what I have so far. I can call the most recent subfolder.

where input_dir is the copyfrom path

for folders, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(input_dir):

```
for subfolder in subfolders:

    max([os.path.join(input_dir,d) for d in os.listdir(input_dir)], key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question? This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages.

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

Use [lucidity](https://lucidity.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tutorial.html#) to parse the naming convention.

```
from lucidity import Template
import pathlib

COPY_FROM = 'C:\Users\lexluthorella\Documents\Test_dir'
COPY_TO = 'C:\Users\lexluthorella\Documents\Fake_sftp'

template1 = Template('Template1', '{month}-{year}')
template2 = Template('Template2', '{Location}\{Location}-{year} Monthly file.xlsx')

def get_newest_subfolder(input_dir) -> str:
      return max([os.path.join(input_dir, d) for d in os.listdir(input_dir)], key=os.path.getmtime)

def matches_naming_scheme(path: str, template: Template):
    try:
        template.parse(path)
        return True
    except lucidity.ParseError as e:
        return False

newest_sub = get_newest_subfolder(COPY_FROM)
copy_from_info = template1.parse(pathlib.Path(newest_sub).parts[-1])

matching_xlsx = [file for file in os.listdir(newest_sub) \
                 if matches_naming_scheme(file, template1)]

output_info = {**copy_from_info, **{'Location': 'Location A'}}
output_dir = os.path.join(COPY_TO, template2.format(output_info))
```

I think this is what you need or can be adapted to fit.

Comment: @georgewalker45 COPY_FROM and input_dir are the same paths. Also Im getting an error "ValueError: Placeholder name contains invalid characters" for line: template2 = Template('Template2', '{Location]\{Location}-{year} Monthly file.xlsx'). Can you elaborate on the {Location]\{Location} as I thought that would be the structure to hold the locations?

Comment: Oops, I used a {...] instead of {...}

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain the following in your code? Unsure what the [-1] is doing exactly here? copy_from_info = template1.parse(pathlib.Path(newest_sub).parts[-1])

Comment: Indexing a list with [-1] gets the last element in the list. pathlib.Path has a property called 'parts' that splits that the filepath into a list list of its part with the first part being the highest level directory in the path and the last part being the file itself with extension if present. `newest_sub` is a path to the desired folder which follows the naming convention as specified. Lucidity can parse this naming convention, so that's what this line of code is doing.

Comment: I cant get this to work and its not throwing an error. Advise?